# Тип данных в массиве

Tags: javascript

[image]

У меня есть двумерный массив, из которого я выбираю нужный мне массив в массиве функцией которая принимает в качестве первого аргумента массив массивов, и второй аргумент это индекс массива. Дело в том, что возвращаемый массив представлен на картинке. В консоли изначально отображается как объект. Мне нужно что бы было как на следующем массиве, который я создал в ручную. Что не так с моим первым массивом ?

Comment: Возле знака 'i' на голубом фоне пишет: value evaluated just now. Как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Причина в асинхронности загрузки. Исправил, когда инициировал массив после загрузки ajax